# Is it an error in that code to get current user of Wordpress?pretty simple but i am stuck

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Watching video about plugin creation and 2 lines af code make me stuck.
Maybe you know why the author call get_current_user() and not assign its value?
Maybe there is an error? Should be like that:

```
global $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

What do you think?[image: here is the full func code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `global` keyword, you can’t assign a value, it is just for bringing global variables into the local scope. That specific function ultimately sets a global variable, and doing it that way (although the order doesn’t matter) gives you access to that variable.

That function, however, also returns the same value, so there is no need to bring a global scoped value into local, it can just be used directly.

Older WordPress code tended to use more global variables, but in the recent years there’s been a trend of trying to encapsulate them in helper functions so some of the “magic” goes away, and this author might have some legacy code or mindset.

**EDIT**

There used to be a function called [`get_currentuserinfo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/) that was deprecated in 4.5. That function did the following:

> Populate global variables with information about the currently logged in user.

And the pattern for using it was:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Although I don't know which video you watched, I'm guessing that the person just blindly replaced `get_currentuserinfo()` with `wp_get_current_user()` and although weird, it technically works still.

Comment: Wow, great explanation Chris. Understand that wp_get_current_user(); return the same value and its like helper function to avoid using global variables. But there is 1 question to you. Can you say why the author didnt assigned the value of func wp_get_current_user()? It happen that he didnt even need to use this function?

Comment: @goodjobman, hopefully my edit makes sense and brings more context

Comment: totally true. yes it can be just a copy paste of get_currentuserinfo from codex. Thanks  a lot for examples Chris. Good luck from Ukraine...

Comment: @goodjobman, if you feel that this or the other solution answers your question, would you please accept it so that this may be marked as closed?

Answer (score 0):

Try as the image contains syntax error.

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$aleproperty_item['post_author'] = $current_user->ID;
```

Same code without syntax error.

Comment: Thank you Anders. Seems the author make a mistake here. Have a good day..